# Prolog: How to find a specific element in a list?

Tags: list, prolog, element

I have to implement this predicate:

```
predicate(+connections, +[index,position], -leftConnections);
```

The connections variable is a list which looks like this:

```
(conn(symbol1, element11, element21), conn(symbol2, element12, element22), etc)
```

I have to find the connection that has the symbol equal to the index variable.
Then, it has to verify which of the two elem is equal to the position variable, and retain the other (let's call it `new_pos`); next, remove the connection found and search which of the other connections has in any of the two elements, the `new_pos`, and retain the new symbol found.

Example:

```
predicate([conn(1,P1,P2), conn(4,P2,P3), conn(3,P3,P1), conn(2,P6,P7)], [1, P2], left);

index = 1, position = P2 => new_position = P1 => new_symbol = 3
leftConnections = [conn(4,P2,P3), conn(3,P3,P1), conn(2,P6,P7)]
```

Code is appreciated!

Comment: Code _is_ appreciate—what have **you** tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in every programming language, you must break this down into steps. The first step is, in your own words, "find the connection that has the symbol equal to the index variable."

This is quite simple:

```
predicate(Connections, [Index,Position], Remaining) :-
    select(conn(Index, Position, _), Connections, Remaining).
predicate(Connections, [Index, Position2], Remaining) :-
    select(conn(Index, _, Position2), Connections, Remaining).
```

Both of those have an anonymous variable which is the `new_pos` we want to retain, so let's keep it:

```
predicate(Connections, [Index, Position], Remaining) :-
    select(conn(Index, Position, NewPos), Connections, Remaining).
predicate(Connections, [Index, Position2], Remaining) :-
    select(conn(Index, NewPos, Position2), Connections, Remaining).
```

Another approach:

```
predicate(Connections, [Index, Position], Remaining) :-
    select(conn(Index, Position, NewPos), Connections, Remaining) ;
    select(conn(Index, NewPos, Position), Connections, Remaining).
```

In fact this would be perfect, but we need somewhere to pass `NewPos` out from, or Prolog will never show us what it unified to.

```
select_position(Connections, [Index,Pos], Remaining, NewPos) :-
    select(conn(Index, Pos, NewPos), Connections, Remaining) ;
    select(conn(Index, NewPos, Pos), Connections, Remaining).
```

Your next step is to find the connection. This isn't hard either:

```
find_with_position(Position, Connections, Connection) :-
    member(Connection, Connections),
    (Connection = conn(_, Position, _) ;
     Connection = conn(_, _, Position)).
```

Both of these have some special-case logic to handle the fact that either item could be the right one. You may want to consider either using lists so you can just use member.

Gluing these together isn't hard:

```
predicate(Connections, [Index, Position], Remaining, Target) :-
    select_position(Connections, [Index, Position], Remaining, NewPos),
    find_with_position(NewPos, Remaining, conn(Target,_,_)).
```

Try it:

```
?- predicate([conn(1,p1,p2), conn(4,p2,p3), 
              conn(3,p3,p1), conn(2,p6,p7)], [1, p2], Left, T).
Left = [conn(4, p2, p3), conn(3, p3, p1), conn(2, p6, p7)],
T = 3 ;
false.
```

You have a lot of problems here. If you're learning Prolog for a class, I encourage you to take a tutorial, such as [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) or [Amzi Adventure](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I managed to do what I had to, which was to get, in your example, conn(4,p2,p3), and to have a leftover: [conn(4,p2,p3), conn(3,p3,p1), conn(2,p6,p7)], which must be used next.